# How to refer to 'this' cell in a conditional formatting formula?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

For a field I have conditional formatting with custom formula: `=today()>C8+14` and `=today()>C8+30` with different styling, basically I want to have a visual styling to highlight older and oldest stuff, two weeks and month. This works. Column `C` have a date, row can be any row *`N`*, so `C$`*`N`* does not help.

However the problem is that I have new rows all the time and it would be easier just to copy-paste the field with rules, and change the date. Rules, however stay as referring to the original here `C$`*`N`* cell.

Could I replace the specific `C$`*`N`* with a `this()`, `self()` or is there something like that - to make it more generic copy/pasteable conditional formatting?

Comment: Well now i started doing that, with row1 references. With same formulae on all rows `=today()>C2+14` it works on also on `C14, C15, C16, ...` but why?? it should not?? some implicit 'this'? Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14406422/stacko/spreadsheetthis.png and link to Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VwzWFNnsorzEk9ls8M6esG6JJh_pjNJofxMffCZ0XH8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `this()` is sensible.  `INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)` is ridiculous.  _the correct answer belongs to @markus-amalthea-magnuson_ imho. thank you+1

Answer (score 17):

Generally: the way to refer to "this" cell is to enter notation for the upper-left corner of the range being formatted. For example, if the range is C1:C, then C1 means "this cell".

For example, formatting C1:C with custom formula

```
=C1 < today() - 14
```

will format all cells in C with dates two weeks in the past.

---

If the range you want to format begins with row 8, and you think you may be inserting rows above that (thus shifting the range), then this formula can be used:

```
=and(C1 < today() - 14, row(C1) >= 8)
```

The formatting will apply only to rows starting with 8, but  the range being the entire column, the formula will handle insertion of rows above row 8.

Comment: the question was for retrieving "this cell" in conditional formatting.  @markus-amalthea-magnuson has the right answer which is dependent upon knowing the "notation" ahead of time (which is impossible when inside conditional formatting since it must fit a entire range)

Answer (score 10):

This is the shortest possible way I've found to reference the current cell in conditional formatting spanning a range: `INDIRECT("RC",FALSE)`. Documentation is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).

Comment: that's not documentation (i mean, your link points to what they think is documentation, but w/o this SO solution, nobody would ever know that this is the solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following combination of functions.

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

You can write complex logics with it.

E.g., Check if this cell's value is equal to this month, and the right cell's value is greater than date of month.

```
=AND(EQ(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),MONTH(TODAY()),GT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1),DAY(TODAY()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on @user79865's answer, we need to refer to `this` cell with a `$` sign. For example,

1. Custom role of when the cell's value is "Yes":

   ```
   =$C1="Yes".
   ```
2. Custom role of when the value is an odd number:

   ```
   =(Int($C1/2)-$C1/2)<>0
   ```

More examples [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413).

Comment: `$` does not mean `this` here