# google sheets checkbox conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a schedule where I use inspector name, job number and then checkboxes to book the inspector on the visit date

[image]

What I'm looking to do is if an inspector is booked in a job on lets say jan 3rd and then in another job also in jan 3rd then fill the cells (Inspector name, job and date checked) in yellow then, if an inspector is booked for 3 jobs on the same day fill the cells (Inspector name, job and date checked) in red

Example:

[image]

If someone can help me to figure out a conditional format formula for this it would be much appreciated

Comment: The default values for checkboxes are TRUE and FALSE. If your checkboxes use the default values, the fhe formula could look this way: `=A4` Do you know how to set a custom formula for conditional formatting?

Comment: Rubén what do you mean =A4?

Comment: I have no clue 

Comment: There are already several answered questions you might find helpful like https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79846/88163 Also look the list of Related questions to the right. If after studying some of them you still need help, please update the question. Tip: include a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view.

Comment: Non of them cover what I’m looking to acomplish

Comment: Another tip: Briefly describe your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Update the question? Isn’t it clear what I wrote? I just need a conditional format formula

Comment: It's clear what you want but, IMHO it's not a great question for this site because it doesn't include a baseline of what you know and didn't describe your search/research efforts. Anyway, I posted and answer, I hope that it's clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

The default values for checkboxes are TRUE and FALSE. If your checkboxes use the default values, the conditional formatting custom formula should look this way:

```
=A4
```

In the context of the conditional formatting feature of Google Sheets that means *apply the conditional formatting when the value of `A4` is true*. Instead of `A4` you should use as reference the cell address of the top-left cell cell of the range with the checkboxes for be formatted.

Please note that `A4` is a relative reference.

References

- [Add formulas and functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en)
- [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)