# Conditional Format cell if the value is just text or a reference

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How to Conditional Format cell in Spreadsheet based on whether the value is just text or a referenced cell from another tab

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79846/highlight-all-cells-in-a-range-that-contain-a-formula-in-google-sheets Has the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight all cells in a range that contain a formula in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79846/highlight-all-cells-in-a-range-that-contain-a-formula-in-google-sheets)